# SIMPLIS VPWL & IPWL resistor

Tags: mosfet, resistors, simulation, converter

I am trying to define R<sub>DS(on)</sub> to simulate the MOSFET to be used in one of the converter topologies in SIMPLIS.

There are two different types of resistor in SIMPLIS defined as below:

- VPWL: The resistor current is controlled by the terminal voltage
- IPWL: The resistor voltage is controlled by the resistor current.

Here are the pictures of the VPWL and a random N-type MOSFET's R<sub>DS(on)</sub> values below.

Since the variables of the VPWL or IPWL are defined according to its terminal I can't use V<sub>GS</sub>. On the other hand, the Id graph is also given by V<sub>GS</sub>.

What is the correct way of defining R<sub>DS(on)</sub> by looking at these graphs? How should I think of it?

[image]

Source: From the SIMPLIS simulation

[image]

Source: ON Semiconductor - N-Channel Power Mosfet - NTB5860NL,NTP5860NL,NVB5860NL,  https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntb5860nl-d.pdf

Comment: I would not bother going into that type of modeling for a MOSFET. You can use a simple voltage-controlled switch - and you define a fixed resistance for the \$r_{DS(on)}\$ and that is perfectly suited for evaluating conduction losses. You can supplement the switch with a modeled diode - and the PWL resistance does this well - and then add a non-linear capacitance with the PWL capacitor. Or you can use an existing model  (or create yours) but I doubt it does model \$r_{DS(on)}\$ variations with gate-source voltage.

Comment: Hello Sir, actually ı am trying to set-up bode plot for phase shift converter which you had provided me an example before. so ı saw PWL resistance in your schematic. I want to make same schematic as yours but ı dont how to put datasheets of the mosfet into PWL resistance especially for Rds-on.  @VerbalKint

Comment: Hello, in this case, why not downloading the free 120+ examples [here](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Book%20Collection.zip) from my webpage and you will have the phase-shifted converter ready to simulate: press F9 and there you go : )

Comment: Hello Sir, i am really a fan of your studies and thanks alot for your nice explanations. If you dont mind, could you please give me a summary of how should ı define the Rds-on into PWL resistance based on the datasheets that ı provided in the question ? ı would like to learn it from the beginning as well. Best regards sir @VerbalKint

Comment: I'm not sure you can because the resistance will "see" the drain current and the voltage across its terminals is the drain-source voltage. However, this voltage should the gate-source voltage so you see the problem. Keep it simple and either use SPICE for simulating a complete MOSFET model or use a simple switch as a first approximation.

Comment: Isn’t the whole point of SIMPLIS that it takes the SPICE model and automatically generates the PWL version of the model itself?